# C++ "unsigned" classes

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I'm writing some object code for processing fractional data (as opposed to floating-point data), and so far have the following:

```
 class frac {
    public:
       int numerator;
       unsigned int denominator;
 };
```

**My question is:**
How can I configure my class definition such that writing `unsigned frac foo;` makes an object identical to `frac foo;`, except `int numerator;` would become `unsigned int numerator;`?

**Edit:**
While ordinarily I'd just use a template (`frac <unsigned>`), this code is going into a larger math API, and I'd prefer the final product to use the `unsigned frac` syntax

**Extension:**
Many answers have stated that it is not possible to implement the `unsigned frac` syntax, but does anyone know why not? Does the C++ compiler have some special processing rule that accommodates for the existing `unsigned` types, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Unsigned is a type and not an operator. That should answer your edit. ;-)

Comment: @Maikel I understand, but it seems to act like more of a modifier in some cases (`unsigned long`, `unsigned char`, etc.), and I am looking for a way to extend it's use in that respect to my `frac` class.

Comment: There's no way to make that exact syntax work.

Comment: The rules for processing "unsigned" are a bit of a mess, but it is not a modifier.  `unsigned long` is a built in simple type (which is unusual in having embedded white space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve such things with Templates. For example

```
template <class Integral>
class frac {
  public:
    Integral numerator;
    std::make_unsigned_t<Integral> denominator;
};
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned

You can use this class like this:

```
frac<int> signed;
frac<unsigned> nonnegative;
```

Comment: I know that the same result can be achieved with a template, but I was wondering if there was any way to keep the `unsigned frac` syntax, as opposed to `frac <unsigned>`.

Comment: I do not think that is possible. What is wrong with templates?

Comment: @ChefCyanide, perhaps you could do `typedef frac<int> ufrac_t; typedef frac<unsigned> frac_t;`. It would **not** allow you to say `unsigned frac`, but it would prevent you having write `frac<int>` and `frac<unsigned>` throughout your code. That being said, I have never worked with template classes in C++, so I am not sure if a *typedef* like that is even legal. Can someone more experienced or knowledgeable verify?

Comment: @SpencerDoak Yes, that implementation of `typedef` does work in C++ (and it's probably what I'll end up using if I can't get `unsigned frac` to work), but I'm curious if there is a way to use the existing `unsigned`syntax used by the default C++ types.

Comment: I propose to `typedef` (or use `using`) with multiple integer sizes then. It might turn out that `int` is too small. `typedef frac<uint64_t> ufrac64_t` etc

Comment: @Maikel Good idea! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible. You can achieve something similar using templates:

```
template<typename T>
class frac_template
{
public:
    T numerator;
    unsigned int denominator;
};

class frac : public frac_template<int> {};
class ufrac : public frac_template<unsigned int> {};
```